# I get this error when accessing a website"Error while accessing the database You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: sql, syntax, mariadb

I keep getting this error:

> "Error while accessing the database
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
select count(*) 
from course_catalog cc 
INNER JOIN classes c ON cc.course_id = c.course_id 
INNER JOIN reservation r ON c.class_id = r.class_id 
where r.student_id ="
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: `where r.student_id ="` Equals what? You need to add a value at the end. Or is that an empty varchar?

Comment: Please add MariaDB tag

Answer (score 0):

`"` is not a valid identifier. It seems likes you're supposed to pass a student id (an integer) to be compared with `r.student_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You have " in the end of the sql query. Make your query properly by providing appropriate condition.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last part, adding a value to compare against.

- For example, against `123`:

  ```
  select count(*) 
  from course_catalog cc 
  INNER JOIN classes c ON cc.course_id = c.course_id 
  INNER JOIN reservation r ON c.class_id = r.class_id 
  where r.student_id = 123
  ```
- Or against `null`:

  ```
  select count(*) 
  from course_catalog cc 
  INNER JOIN classes c ON cc.course_id = c.course_id 
  INNER JOIN reservation r ON c.class_id = r.class_id 
  where r.student_id is null
  ```